# Mixed static and dynamic link on Mac OS

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I want to use gcc to produce a shared library, but i want to link some other libraries it depends on statically. Now to produce the "standard" dynamically linked output file i use

```
gcc -dynamiclib *.o -lfoo -lbar -o outfile
```

which would be

```
gcc -shared *.o -lfoo -lbar -o outfile
```

on for a binutils `ld` on a linux system. Now if i want libfoo and libbar to be linked statically, I can name the static libraries directly

```
gcc -dynamiclib *.o /usr/lib/libfoo.a /usr/lib/libbar.a -o outfile
```

however, that way i have to look for the library files myself. GNU binutils `ld` supports this:

```
gcc -shared *.o -l:libfoo.a -l:libbar.a -o outfile
```

but apple's `ld` doesnt.

- Is there a way to make apple's `ld` look for the static libraries himself?
- If not, is there another way that would avoid naming the exact location of the archives, e.g. producing an intermediate output file out of the object files requiring libfoo and libbar with the `-static` switch and linking that file together with the remaining objectfiles to create the dynamic object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [QA1393](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1393/),

> Normally, the linker goes through each path in the search paths one at a time to find a dynamic version of the library. If none is found, it goes through each of those paths looking for a static version of the same library. There is no way to choose a static library over a corresponding dylib if both libraries are in the same directory without using the -l linker option and absolute paths to each library.

As recommended by QA1393, you can place your static libraries in a different directory, use `-L/path/to/static/libraries` before other occurrences of `-L` that could point to dynamic libraries, and `-search_paths_first` so that the linker tries both .dylib (which won’t be there) and .a in the first search path before searching the next search path and so forth.

Comment: i'm afraid that doesn't solve the problem at all... what i'm asking for is the comfort of -l<libname> resolution - if i wanted to put the libraries somewhere or add their paths i can as well name the archive files directly.

Comment: If there is no <libname>.dylib in the search paths, the linker will use <libname>.a. However, if there is a dynamic version available, you cannot prevent the linker from using it. If that’s the case, I’m afraid there’s no solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. As it turned out, there seems to be no way to link libraries statically without specifying the full path to the .a-file.

However, there seems to be [neat trick](https://web.archive.org/web/20110412144443/http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_4.html#SEC25) in `Makefile`'s allowing for smooth usage.

```
vpath %.a /opt/local/lib
.LIBPATTERNS lib%.a lib%.dylib lib%.so

STATICLIBS = -lssh2

libmy.dylib: my1.o my2.o $(STATICLIBS)
  g++ -dynamiclib -o libmy.dylib $^
```

Note how the `$(STATICLIBS)` variable is put in the dependencies. Make will not treat dependecies with an '-l' prefix as files - but rather as libraries. Using the above `vpath` magic make looks up the libraries and put the full path on the commandline to g++.